# which pattern from string another string matches

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a column variable that I want to split into three factor variables. There are the factor variables I want to create:

```
goal<-c('newref', 'meow', 'woof')
area<-c('eco', 'social', 'bank')
fr<-c('demo', 'hist', 'util')
```

And the current variable looks more or less like that:

```
code<-c('goal\\\\meow', 'area\\\\bank', 'area\\\\bank', 'fr\\\\utilitarian', 'fr\\\\history')
```

And let's say the dataframe is something like that

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3,4,5), var2=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), code=code)
```

So I would like to create 3 new columns, one per each factor variable, and use a regular expression that detected what it belongs to. So for example row number one should look as follows:

```
row1<-data.frame(var1=1, var2=c('a'), code=c('goal\\\\meow'), goal=2, area=NA, fr=NA)
```

Also note that the value of the factor variables is an abbreviation of the value in code (eg, history / hist).
 The database is likely to have 10000 entries, so I would really appreciate any hints on this.
Thank you!

Comment: Does it  have to be a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

We can define a function that finds the position of the factor variable that, when used as a regular expression, finds a match in the `code` column:

```
find_match <- function(code, matches) {
    apply(sapply(matches, grepl, code), 1, match, x=T)
}
```

If there is no match, this function returns `NA` for that row.

Next, we can simply use `mutate` from `dplyr` to add each column of factors:

```
df %>% mutate(goal = find_match(code, goal),
              area = find_match(code, area),
              fr = find_match(code, fr))
```

Which gives:

```
  var1 var2              code goal area fr
1    1    a      goal\\\\meow    2   NA NA
2    2    b      area\\\\bank   NA    3 NA
3    3    c      area\\\\bank   NA    3 NA
4    4    d fr\\\\utilitarian   NA   NA  3
5    5    e     fr\\\\history   NA   NA  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with tidyverse tools like the pipe %>% and dplyr:

Separate breaks up the code column into two with the separator you specify.

Because "\" is a special character in regex you have to escape each \ you want to look for with another .

Spread converts it from tall form to wide form as you needed.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate(code, into = c("colName", "value"), sep = "\\\\\\\\") %>% 
  spread(colName, value)
```